# Почему повторяется фон для tr внутри td?

Tags: html, css

Есть такой код

```
<table class="table last_auth_flayter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Дата</th>
            <th>IP адрес</th>
            <th>Город</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td class="last_auth_date">02.06.2016 11:07</td>
           <td class="last_auth_ip">127.0.0.1</td>
           <td class="last_auth_city"></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

```
tbody > tr {
    //ширина картинки 360 пикселей на 32
    background: url(../images/bg_last_auth.png) no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
}
```

**Вот как работает в FireFox**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А вот так, работает в хроме** - каждый `td` начинает фон с начала

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить, чтобы в хроме отображалось так же, как и в FireFox?
Для `td` стилей особо нет, только цвета меняет...

https://jsfiddle.net/ktjzcshx/1/

Comment: `tr` - это вся строка, а `td` - ячейка внутри строки. если стиль с фоном применяется к строке, то эффекта, как на нижней картинке, быть не должно. так что либо есть ещё какие-то стили для ячеек `td`, о которых речь не идёт, либо магия имхо

Comment: Все стили для тд почистил, я заметил, что хром подставляет свои стили некоторые, но переопределяя их - нужного результата все равно не добиваюсь. Сам непойму что за беда.

Comment: смотрите через отладчик на ваши `tr` и `td` - необходимо понять, откуда берётся бекграунд на ячейке, какое свойство и из какой строки файла стилей его туда добавляет. а уже потом думать, почему оно не работает во всех браузерах. возможно, у вас там спрятались вендорные префиксы (а-ля -webkit- или -moz-) у свойств рядов/ячеек, которые каким-то образом влияют

Comment: Я через отладчик и работаю, для проверки, и там все верно написано, что бэкграунд у tr, а у td только цвета разные. Префиксы не использую, так как не использую новых свойств, которые могут не поддерживаться

Comment: можете на jsfiddle или прям тут в сниппете рабочий пример сделать?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ktjzcshx/1/ - опять же, в мозиле - все хорошо, а в хроме - та же беда

Comment: похоже [старый баг](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35697)

Comment: @user190134 забавно, но сегодня я тоже словил этот баг в хроме. выкрутился проставлением бекграунда не в `tr`, а в `td`. иного выхода не вижу

Comment: Я на дивах сверстал это чудо, так как у меня бг шириной 360пикселей, а если подставлять в td , то получилась бы та же история